# PHP Обработать данные строки в массив

Tags: php, php7

Я получаю из стороннего сервиса по API показания температуры за последний час. Данные поступают в виде строки, где данные отображаются за каждые 10 минут.

Пример:

```
200504, 0600, 0, 262.3, 1.399, 6.097, 2.15, 
200504, 0610, 0, 251.2, 1.29, 6.08, 2.09,
200504, 0620, 0, 249.4, 1.685, 5.921, 2.44,
200504, 0630, 0, 249.5, 1.465, 5.904, 2.27,
200504, 0640, 0, 247.7, 1.801, 6.214, 2.61,
200504, 0650, 0, 246.9, 1.908, 6.532, 3.04,
```

Перед мной стоит задача посчитать *среднее значение последнего значения каждого ряда*. **[2.15, 2.09, 2.44, 2.27, 2.61, 3.04]**

До этого было реализовано как обработать последнюю строку и записать её в массив.

```
$str = '190227, 2020, 9, 245.8, 2.886, 5.753, 0';

$pattern = '/([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*)/m';

preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);

$result =  [
    "Date" =>  intval($matches[1]),
    "Time" =>  intval($matches[2]),
    "h" => intval($matches[3]),
    "Deg.M" => floatval($matches[4]),
    "m/s" => floatval($matches[5]),
    "deg.C" => floatval($matches[6]),
    "mm/h" => floatval($matches[7])
];
```

Подскажите вариант реализации записи этих данных в двумерный массив и обработки среднего значения.

Answer (score 0):

берете текст и разбиваете на строки

```
$rows = explode("\n", $txt);
```

проходите по строкам, удаляете последнюю запятуаю и разбиваете по запятым. берете последний элемент.

```
$values = explode(",",  trim($r, ","));
$last = array_pop($values);
```

складываете это дело в промежуточный массив, сразу деленое на общее число строк

```
$data[] = $last/count($values);
```

суммируете среднее

```
$avg = array_sum($data);
```

либо с регулярками

```
preg_match_all("/([\d.]+),(?=\n|$)/", $txt, $matches);
$result = array_sum($matches[1])/count($matches[1]);
```